# Interval arithmetic problems

Tags: elementary-set-theory, interval-arithmetic

I'm trying to solve a few examples with intervals. The problem is I'm confused, and I couldn't find much info on the internet that could help me. I'll list the exercises and share my thoughts and answers.

1. $conv\mathbb{N}$

Well, it seems to me that $[1,\infty]$ is the smallest convex set that covers it.

2. $conv\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2=1\}$

$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2\le1\}$ - as above.

3. $\mathbb{N}+[0,1]$

This one I'm confused by. Is it an ordinary union, that is $[0,1)\cup\mathbb{N}$? Or do I add the interval to every element in $\mathbb{N}$, making it $\{[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],...\}$? Or is it something entirely different?

4. $[0,1]^2+\{(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$
5. $[0,1]^2+\{(t,t)|t\in[0,1]\}$

Here, I'm not sure what $[0,1]^2$ represents. Is it just a multiplication, i.e. $[0,1]*[0,1]=[0,1]$? Or is it a unit square? Or something different? As in the previous case, I don't know how to go about adding these.

6. $[-1,1]^2+\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2\le1\}$

Well, it's a more complicated version of the previous ones and I don't know how to approach it.

I'd appreciate if someone could answer the questions and/or point me to some literature that explains it in a clear fashion.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure as to the notation regarding $+$  for questions 3 and 6; it does seem rather ambiguous to me. As for your questions on the $[0,1]^2$ notation, think of it like $[0,1] \times [0,1]$: the unit square in $\Bbb R^2$. That's the convention usually used here, at least in my experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A + B = { a + b : a in A, b in B } is accepted notation.

For 4 and 5, $[0,1]^2$ is the unit square and + vector addition.
Similar for 6.

Refer to the source of these problems for clues about notation.

Comment: Thank you. Could you check my answers? They're asking me to sketch those. In 6, I wasn't sure how to write it down in a simpler way, but I think that's what it looks like.

https://i.imgur.com/HPYLCtM.jpg